# asp.net Entity Framework Row Count Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm attempting a simple row count in Entity Framework, however I'm struggling with syntax. The complete method I'm working on is shown below:

```
public void Limit_Basket()
{
    var _db = new WLL.DAL.Context();
    IQueryable<Basket> query = _db.Baskets;
    String userName = User.Identity.Name;
    var count = WLL.DAL.Basket.Count(t => t.User == userName);
    if (count >= 2)
    {
        CheckoutImageBtn.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        CheckoutImageBtn.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

The issue is with the lambda expression:

```
var count = WLL.DAL.Basket.Count(t => t.User == userName);
```

VS states no definition exists for `Count`. Does anyone know how I can correct this syntactical error? I've tried a multitude of ways to set the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `Count()` on the type `WLL.DAL.Basket`, but you should call `Count()` on the `IQueryable<Basket> query` instance like this:

```
var count = query.Count(t => t.User == userName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to use the count on the query variable? Like so:

```
var count = query.Count(t => t.User == userName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use `_db`, not the `WLL.DAL..`. Also you can shorten your code a little.

```
public void Limit_Basket()
{
    var _db = new WLL.DAL.Context();

    var count = _db.Buskets.Count(t => t.User == User.Identity.Name);

    CheckoutImageBtn.Visible = count < 2;   
}
```